# Post a picture fia Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to post a message with picture (from a public URL, not from my albums) to group's wall:

```
$response = $facebook->api("/$group_id/feed", "POST", array(
    'access_token=' => $access_token,
    'message' => 'This is a test message',
    'picture' => 'http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/agydwb6_460s.jpg',
    )
);
```

Everything is fine, but I can't see a picture itself:

[image: my post]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While posting a `feed`, you must specify a `link` along with a `picture` if want to add a picture to the feed; else its not a feed. Logical right?

**Code:**

```
'access_token=' => $access_token,
'message' => 'This is a test message',
'link' => '{link-to-share}',
'picture' => 'http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/agydwb6_460s.jpg',
```

If you dont want link, but just  a picture, then you should simply upload the picture instead- by  using [**`/photos`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos)

**Code**:

```
$response = $facebook->api(
    "/$group_id/photos",
    "POST",
    array (
      'url' => '{image-url}',
    )
);
```